# WooCommerce - no confirmation after adding product to cart

Tags: wordpress, callback, cart, woocommerce, confirmation

I'm not sure it's meant to be like this, but when I click the 'Add to cart' button on a product (when viewing a page of products), no visual confirmation is given to the user.

Am I missing a JS file? Or maybe I need a div with a specific ID in my HTML for the message to be displayed in? Or do I need to create my own JS callback method to handle when the product has been added?

I've researched this, and there's surprisingly little info on it (so maybe I broke something?).

I have WC's "Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on product archives" option ticked, and I can confirm that products are actually being added to the cart - the user just doesn't know anything about it!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - I had unticked WC's "Enable WooCommerce CSS styles". It should come with a warning in my opinion! :)

Comment: Where is this option I cant find it?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be there in the latest version(s) of WooCommerce: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Enable+WooCommerce+CSS+styles%22